# jQuery change image onclick of image clicked and others

Tags: jquery, html

I have a question regarding jQuery.  I have three images that are, in essence, the same.  The difference is that one of the images (let's call it the 'active' image) is a different color, while the other two images are the same.

Here's a visual piece:  I have a "promo" banner that has three images of, say, arrows next to it.  Depending on the arrow image that you click, a different promo image is displayed (there are three promo images all together -- the same as the arrows).

I'd love it if I could get the "active" arrow to be displayed in one color, while the "inactive" arrows are another color.  When I click on another arrow, the original "active" one because "inactive" and the one I just clicked on becomes "active". I'm sure it can be done, I just have no idea how to do it :/

Here's the HTML that I'm working with:

```
<div class="rotation_container">
  <a class="rotator" id="rotator_1" href="#"><img class="cycle_icon" id="r1" src="images/promo/rotator_active.png" /></a>
  <a class="rotator" id="rotator_2" href="#"><img class="cycle_icon" id="r2" src="images/promo/rotator_inactive.png" /></a>
  <a class="rotator" id="rotator_3" href="#"><img class="cycle_icon" id="r3" src="images/promo/rotator_inactive.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do it using classes. When an arrow is clicked you set all of them to a inactive class except the one that was clicked, which you would set it to a active class.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work with your current markup:

```
$('a.rotator').click(function () {
  // Make all inactive
  $('div.rotation_container img').attr('src', 'images/promo/rotator_inactive.png');

  // Make the one that was clicked active
  $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/promo/rotator_active.png');
});
```

But really, you should be achieving this via CSS. Remove the `<img>` elements and apply a `.active` class to the active anchor:

```
<div class="rotation_container">
  <a class="rotator active" id="rotator_1" href="#"></a>
  <a class="rotator" id="rotator_2" href="#"></a>
  <a class="rotator" id="rotator_3" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

You can apply the active/inactive image through CSS:

```
a.rotator { background:url(images/promo/rotator_inactive.png) }
a.rotator.active { background:url(images/promo/rotator_active.png) }
```

And the `.click` handler becomes much simpler:

```
$('a.rotator').click(function () {
  $('a.rotator.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: I honestly can't believe I didn't think of the CSS method.  I'll definitely keep it in mind!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rotator').click(function(){
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('_inactive', '_active'));

        $('.rotator:not(#'+$(this).attr('id')+') img').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('_active', '_inactive'));
        });

        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

1) if ".rotator" is clicked, then:

2) find "img" inside and replace "_inactive" with "_active" in the src.

3) every other "img" inside ".rotator" becomes "_inactive" instead of "_active"

4) "return false;" to make the click not scroll the page to the top